Tableau Sum is already an aggregation and cannot further aggregate
I’m trying to take the sum of the count of a column and it’s telling me sum is already an aggregate and can not further aggregate.
Attempt: Sum(Count of Cases)
The count of cases is a calculated file I didn’t get the count of cases in a column. Thanks for any help!

If you count up all the cases, that is the sum of all the cases, so it makes sense that you cannot further aggregate them. If you take the distinct count of all the cases, that is the sum of all the non-repeating cases. What specifically are you tying to do? Additionally Tableau treats created calculated fields as new columns.

Thank you for the response! I’m trying to find an average. So I need to take the sum of the count of cases and divide that by the sum count of investigators. But again my problem is that I can’t take the sum of a count. I used windows_sum and that seems to work. But not sure if that’s the appropriate thing to do.

Just take the count, no need to sum it. COUNT([cases]) IS the sum of all the cases.

Nvm! I understand what you’re saying lol thank you friend.

Here is the documentation for count vs distinct count. Read about the difference, I believe you may need a distinct count for your investigators as count will count the same investigator more than once.

Posted a synopsis of the comments as an answer so if others face the same issue, they may find the solution easier.

Count is the sum of all the cases.
See count vs distinct count documentation here.
